# How to find the correct uiwebview height based on the html content

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am using the following code to find the UIWebview height based on the html content, but its not returning exactly correct size. some time it give more size and some times it gives less size.I don't want to show some extra space in uiwebview

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
NSString *desccontentH = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"desc\").offsetHeight;"];
NSLog(@"Webviewheight: %@", desccontentH);
CGSize fittingSize = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
NSLog(@"sizeThatFits:Height%f, width:%f",fittingSize.width, fittingSize.height);
.....
}
```

How to find the correct uiwebview height based on the html content?

Comment: once check this  NSLog(@"check the height %@",NSStringFromCGSize(webView.scrollView.contentSize));

Comment: @ismail i checked its working fine for medium number of text. scrollview content size and sizeThatFits both are return the same size.If content is large number of text that time only some extra size returned..

Answer (score 0):

Use `contentSize` property of `webView`'s `scrollView`.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    CGSize size = webView.scrollView.contentSize;
    NSLog(@"width = %f, height = %f", size.width, size.height);
    ...
}
```

Comment: this is working for medium number of text. if text is some what larger than its not return the exact size.

Comment: can you post an example HTML? or provide more code to understand what's wrong

Comment: use some large text(more than 100 line) with html tag and check the UIwebsize content size with following code "CGSize size = webView.scrollView.contentSize;
    NSLog(@"width = %f, height = %f", size.width, size.height);"

Answer (score 0):

Take this example used for TextView:

```
    CGFloat descriptionContentHeight = [self sizeOfText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n",addressTextView.text] widthOfTextView:addressTextView.frame.size.width withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Light" size:17.5f]].height + 4;

 addressTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-10,8,0,0);
[addressTextView setFrame:CGRectMake(addressTextView.frame.origin.x,addressTextView.frame.origin.y ,addressTextView.frame.size.width, descriptionContentHeight)];


  -(CGSize)sizeOfText:(NSString *)textToMesure widthOfTextView:(CGFloat)width withFont:(UIFont*)font
  {
   CGSize size = [textToMesure sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width-20.0, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
   return size;
   /// FLT_MAX is definded elsewhere :)
   }
```